# Verify String is displaying within Nested JSON using Postman

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am working on Postman to verify some API calls, upon which I have gone through one of the end point, whose response is give below, and I need to make sure that within that JSON response:

```
[
   
    {
        "contact": {
            "id": "k72yk2iwrf",
            "firstName": "Francis",
            "lastName": "Abell",
            "title": "Translational Science Project Manager",
            "company": "Sensei",
            "email": "aa@aa.cpom",
            "fax": {},
            "businessAddress": {
                "line1": "road",
                "line2": "Street",
                "line3": "Suite 710",
                "city": "Boston",
                "country": "US",
                "postalCode": "02210",
                "state": "MA"
            },
            "businessPhone": {
                "number": "123-123-1234",
                "ext": ""
            },
            "homeAddress": {},
            "homePhone": {},
            "mobilePhone": {}
        },
        "registration": {
            "id": "104656",
            "badgeId": "9208113975",
            "eventId": "TESTLIBRA-10"
        }
    },
    {
        "contact": {
            "id": "w4c4f2i7l4",
            "firstName": "Francis",
            "lastName": "Abell",
            "title": "Translational Science Project Manager",
            "company": "Sensei",
            "email": "aa@aa.cpom",
            "fax": {},
            "businessAddress": {
                "line1": "road",
                "line2": "Street",
                "line3": "Suite 710",
                "city": "Boston",
                "country": "US",
                "postalCode": "02210",
                "state": "MA"
            },
            "businessPhone": {
                "number": "123-123-1234",
                "ext": ""
            },
            "homeAddress": {},
            "homePhone": {},
            "mobilePhone": {}
        },
        "registration": {
            "id": "104656",
            "badgeId": "6803424516",
            "eventId": "TESTLIBRA-10"
        }
    }
]
```

I can make sure that `"eventId"` is displaying and it is displaying `"TESTLIBRA-10"` value.
No matter, how long JSON response is, It can verify that this property , along with that value of that property are displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer by myself, what I did was:

```
var jsonArrayData = pm.response.json();

pm.test('EventID property is displaying throughout JSON', function(){
jsonArrayData.each(function(eventID){
    pm.expect(eventID.registration).to.have.property("eventId")
})
})

pm.test('Entered Libra EventID is entered', function(){
jsonArrayData.each(function(eventID){
    pm.expect(eventID.registration.eventId).to.eql("TESTLIBRA-10")
})
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).